# SimpleDateFormat para mes abreviado en 3 caracteres

Tags: java, date, formato, parsear

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de parsear fechas que expresan el mes abreviado a 3 caracteres. Uso un SimpleDateFormar que construyo de la siguiente forma:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm yyyy", new Locale("es")) ;
```

Cuando trato de parsear una fecha con mes septiembre escrita "sep" me da error ya que con este SimpleDateFormat septiembre lo representa como "sept."

¿Cómo puedo lograr que mi SimpleDateFormat sea capaz de leer el mes septiembre representado por "sep"?
Hice varias pruebas cambiando el Locale pero no logré solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase `DateFormatSymbols` de esta forma:

```
 DateFormatSymbols symbols;
 // la inicializas en idioma español, país México:
 symbols = new DateFormatSymbols( new Locale("es", "MX"));  // con MX es sep, con ES (España) es sept.
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm yyyy", symbols);
```

Puedes crear tus propias abreviaturas incluso en mayúsculas con el método `setShortMonths`:

```
 // primero creas el String array
 String[] meses = {"ENE", "FEB","MAR", "ABR", "MAY", "JUN",
                   "JUL", "AGO","SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DIC"};

 // lo configuras así, después de inicializar symbols:
 symbols.setShortMonths(meses);
```

Comment: Muchas, gracias.  Muy útil esta opción.